# Defensively checking inputs in client. Is this a good practice?

Tags: java, web-services

Is it a good practice to defensively check for null/empty inputs in client ? In the server this check is happening of whether or not input is null and an exception is thrown accordingly, should client also make a check in order to avoid a call to the webservice ?

Answer (score 3):

Under the best circumstances, it is a performance improvement, and nothing else.

Under the worst circumstances, the client side checking can drift away from what the server accepts, actually introducing bugs due to inconsistent deployments.

In either case, you don't typically have control over the client environment, so you cannot assume the client-side check was performed.  Malicious users can inject their own client-side code which will permit non-valid inputs to be sent to the server, so server-side checking is still strongly required.

I would recommend that you do client-side checks, but I would also recommend that you take the care to ensure that your client-side checks are synchronized with your server-side checks, such that your client doesn't start filtering inputs in a different manner than your server would.  If that becomes too problematic, error on making the server side checking correct.  It's the only real defense point.

Answer (score 2):

It's good practice to do whatever you need to do to protect your server, whatever that may be.

Always do checking server side, you never know where data is going to come from.

Do checking client side if you have some reason for notifying the user of their mistake before sending data to a server. For example, a client-side validation of an integer input can, e.g., update a warning label as the user is typing without requiring round-trip validation to the server. Client-side checks are essentially a first line of action for displaying clear validation errors to the user, but really they are nothing more than UI performance improvements. If you don't want to do that, then you don't need to do that. If you only want to do that for certain values, you only need to do that for certain values.

Perhaps your server already generates reasonable information about validation errors, in which case you could display those to the client. It really depends on your situation and needs.

For example, lets say the client displays a series of dialogs asking for input before finally sending a request to the server. It's irritating for the user if they aren't notified of an invalid input until *after* they go through the entire series of dialogs. This is a good case for client-side validation at each step of the input.

Note that the cost of client-side validation is that you need to make sure to maintain it to match the actual server-side rules if they change.

It's also good practice to think a little about your specific requirements and choose an appropriate course of action to make sure those requirements are met, rather than asking vague questions about generic, situation-agnostic "good practice".

Personally, I try my best to have server-side validation report useful information, and I don't do any initial client-side validation. I then add client-side validation later, after higher priority work is complete and after determining that the UX would clearly benefit from it.

Comment: Added example about sequence of dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in order to keep the bandwidth and the server load as low as possible, you should always add client-side validation as well. Even a thin-client can do easy validations like null/empty-checks.

If you have some complex validation depending on many different inputs (cross-validation) or maybe complicated checksum calculations, you might skip the client-side validation and do it only on server side.

Server side validation is always needed though, because as you can see, the client cannot be trusted if you would now decide to not validate.

Comment: Server side validation is always needed for other reasons too.  Clients are not ran in a trustworthy environment.  Cross-site scripting, people injecting code in their own clients, custom response code, client-side debugging environments, and simple disabling of client-side features can all be leveraged to circumvent a client-side check, even when it is "enabled".

Comment: @EdwinBuck I didn't exclude any other reasons for server side validation. I just brought up an example fitting his scenario.

Comment: "You should always add client-side validation" is extremely misleading. Perhaps the OP's usage/performance requirements make a server trip a reasonable cost, for example, and not worth the implementation and maintenance effort. When you make statements like that, it is akin to saying "not doing this is Evil(TM)", and now you have a reader blindly making this decision for the same reason people don't use "goto" in C++. The real answer is: If you *want* to do client-side validation, for whatever reason, then you *should*. If you don't want to, for whatever reason, then you shouldn't.

Comment: @JasonC Okay, if people decide to read only half of the sentences I write, then nobody can help them anymore...

Comment: If by the other half you mean the part that says "you should always add client-side validation, unless your validation is complex or involves checksums," that's no less misleading (and doesn't make much sense, logically).

Comment: @JasonC Obviously, the other half was "in order to keep the bandwidth and the server load as low as possible", which will be the only reason why you want client-side validation in 90% of all cases. Stop re-interpreting my answer...

Comment: @noone As I clearly indicated in my first comment, the necessity of that is based on actual performance requirements. I presumed you read that and made the connection to your answer, and assumed you meant some different "other half", since, of course, I already addressed that part.